# How can I solve "import cv2, ImportError: DLL load failed " in Python 3.7 and OpenCV 4.1.1 on VsCode?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a script which detects a face with the webcam of my laptop. In the beginning, I was using Spyder coming with an Anaconda package and it wasn't throwing any ImportError for OpenCV and everything was perfectly fine. Then I wanted to change IDE as I only wanted a change and started using VsCode but as independent of Anaconda. After some improvements in my code it started to throw this ImportError for OpenCV as shown below:

```
    File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/SeniorProject/EE 492/lbp/FaceDetection.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cv2

    ImportError: DLL load failed: Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.
```

**Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.** on the last line is in my mother-tongue and it says The specified module could not be found.
After I got this error message, I thought changing the IDE might be a good idea and switched to Spyder(on Anaconda) again. But I kept getting the same error on this IDE too. Then I searched for the internet and tried everything to help me solve the problem.
Tried to uninstall the OpenCV on anaconda and then re-install or tried the following commands:
conda install opencv-python
conda install opencv-contrib-python
pip3 install opencv-python
pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

I even tried to copy the file named **cv2.cp37-win_amd64.pyd** and paste both to C:\Python34\DLLs and C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages folders but there occurred no change. I even tried PyCharm considering it might help, but no it didn't help either.
I don't know how to solve this problem. Shall I uninstall Anaconda and OpenCV and re-install?
Or maybe there might be something I can do which I didn't come across on the internet. Your help will be muchly appreciated.
Thanks anyway!
I leave the original code of mine below:

```
    import cv2
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    import os
    import scanning as sc


    face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')          
    eye_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    img_counter = 0
    imagePath = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\SeniorProject\EE 492\lbp\images\testing'
    newPath = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\SeniorProject\EE 492\lbp\images\testing2'
    location = []

    while True:
       _, frame = video_capture.read()
       im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
       k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF


     #Detect faces, eyes and smiles in input frame
     faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray, scaleFactor = 1.5, minNeighbors = 3, flags = 
        cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, minSize = (30, 30))

     eyes = eye_classifier.detectMultiScale(im_gray, scaleFactor = 1.5, minNeighbors = 3, flags = 
        cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, minSize=(5, 5), maxSize=(10,10))


     # Draw a rectangle around the faces

     for x, y, w, h in faces:
         cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
         location.append([x,y,w,h])

     # Draw a rectangle around the eyes
     for ex, ey, ew, eh in eyes:
         cv2.rectangle(frame, (ex,ey), (ex+ew, ey+eh), (0, 0, 255), 1)


     # Display the resulting frame
     cv2.imshow('Face Detector', frame)

     if k%256 == 27: #ESC pressed
         break
     elif k%256 == 32: #SPACE pressed
         img_counter += 1
         img_name = "FaceDetect_webcam_{}.png".format(img_counter)
         cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(imagePath, img_name), frame)
         print("{} saved!".format(img_name))

   video_capture.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, I think you are copying the files to a wrong directory, unless you renamed it `Python34` probably is not the 3.7 version you are using. Go to your terminal and type `python —version` check the output, that’s the python version you are currently using. Use `pip install opencv-python` and see if you get the error afterwards

Comment: You were right. Python37 was installed in fact but Python34 was the wrong folder which I do not know where I got it from. But finally I uninstalled Anaconda for ever :) and re-installed Python3.7. Then succesfully managed to download OpenCV and copied to the correct site-packages folder. I checked if it's accomplished correctly on IDLE by typing 'cv2.__version__'  . But I still get the same error. (DLL load failed.) Might there be something wrong with the version of Python? Shall I downgrade it to Python3.6?

Comment: I am not sure if the copying you do is actually correct, did you try what I suggested in my initial answer? If you see that your desired python version is your default, `pip`should install your modules in the correct package folder.

Comment: Yes I have tried what you suggested and it returned the version of python that I'm currently using. That's why I concluded that I was copying to the wrong folder in the beginning and changed later on and then copied to the correct site-packages folder. But then it kept returning the same error message. Then I completely removed Python 3.7.4 and installed 3.7.5, namely upgraded it which worked properly. I also deleted all OpenCV versions and installed 4.1.1 again so that I could be able to start over. Finally it worked and I solved the problem. Now it doesn't throw any DLL error. Thank you!