# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found after installing Nvidia GPU

Tags: python, opencv

***I am facing this issue since I have installed NVIDIA GPU kernel.***

Below is the error stack I am getting.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-458913dbee94> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import cv2
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      5 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: By GPU kernel, you mean you installed Nvidia drivers?

Comment: yes I have used GPU installation

Answer (score 2):

Got the similar issue and seems it is due to open CV. I tried below steps suggested by @code-lukas under link   https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347341/5716310 .This worked for me.

To install opencv-python in anaconda prompt:

```
    python —version
    pip install opencv-python
```